# trying to use the getBooksByAuthor method to return all the books from that author in the Linked List called BookCollection

Tags: python, linked-list, getmethod

Book Object with attributes: Title, Author, Year

```py
class Book():
    def __init__(self, title = "", author = "", year = None):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.year = year
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title
    def getAuthor(self):
        return self.author
    def getYear(self):
        return self.year
    def getBookDetails(self):
        string = ("Title: {}, Author: {}, Year: {}"\
                     .format(self.title, self.author, self.year))
        return string
```

Linked List called `BookCollection`:

```py
class BookCollection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def insertBook(self, book)
        temp = BookCollectionNode(book)
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp
```

Trying to return all the books by a certain author

```py
    def getBooksByAuthor(self, author):
        b = Book()
        if author == b.getAuthor():
            return b.getBookDetails
```

Node class called `BookCollectionNode`:

```py
class BookCollectionNode():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
    def getData(self):
        return self.data
    def getNext(self):
        return self.next
    def setData(self, newData):
        self.data = newData
    def setNext(self, newNext):
        self.next = newNext
```

Using the functions below to use the `getBooksByAuthorMethod`:

```py
b0 = Book("Cujo", "King, Stephen", 1981)
b1 = Book("The Shining", "King, Stephen", 1977)
b2 = Book("Ready Player One", "Cline, Ernest", 2011)
b3 = Book("Rage", "King, Stephen", 1977)
bc = BookCollection()
bc.insertBook(b0)
bc.insertBook(b2)
bc.insertBook(b3)
print(bc.getBooksByAuthor("King, Stephen"))
```

Trying to get all of Stephen Kings books by using this method.  Should return `b0`, `b1`, and `b3`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `getBooksByAuthor`.  Why do you create a new book in it?  Also you don't use `self` in it which means that you're actually not looking at the books of your collection.

Usually, when you do not use `self` in a method, it's either because you want your method to return a constant (which can happen) either because you made an error.

So you need to loop on the books of your collection:

```py
    def getBooksByAuthor(self, author):
        node = self.head
        result = list()  # list of book details with the given author
        while node is not None:  # loop on the nodes the collection
            book = node.getData()
            if book.getAuthor() == author:
                result.append(book.getBookDetails())
            node = node.getNext()  # move to the next book of the collection
        return result
```

Output with the modified `getBooksByAuthor` (and with adding `b1` in your collection, which you forgot):

```py
['Title: Rage, Author: King, Stephen, Year: 1977', 'Title: The Shining, Author: King, Stephen, Year: 1977', 'Title: Cujo, Author: King, Stephen, Year: 1981']
```